# How can I get continuous same characters of specified length from original string by regular expression in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

Source: `'aaabbbccddddhhhhlll'`

I want to get the `'aaa'`, `'bbb'` and `'lll'` by regular expression.

I tried `/([a-z])\1{2}(?!\1)/g`, and I got `'ddd'` and `'hhh'` too, which I do not want.

How should I write the regular expression?

**Note**: I cannot write `'(?<!exp)'` or `'(?<name>exp)'` in Node.js while using RegExp like this:

```
var search_exp = new RegExp('([a-z])(?<!\\1)', 'g');

var search_exp1 = new RegExp('(?<myname>[a-z])\\k<myname>{2}', 'g');
```

I got `'Invalid group'` error for these.

Did I write it wrong, or is there something special in Javascript/Node.js?

Comment: Why is `ddd` and `hhh` not desired? What is the desired output of the example you provided?

Comment: **Note:** `(?exp)` is wrong, because you're missing a character that will tell wether the group is a non-capturing one `(?:exp)`, a look ahead one `(?=exp)` or a negative look ahead one `(?!exp)`.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir `d` is four characters long (consecutive) as is h, OP just wants anything exactly 3 in length

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript RegExps don't have look-behinds `(?<...)` that's why it throws the error, as the only characters that can follow `(?` are:

- `:` : for non-capturing groups
- `=` : for positive look-ahead
- `!` : for negative look-ahead

**Hybrid solution:**

You can get the result of all consecutive substrings and then filter the results like this:

```js
let str = "aaabbbccddddhhhhlll";

let result = str.match(/([a-z])\1+/g)           // match all consecutive characters (at least 2 characters long (you can make at least 3 if you want))
                .filter(s => s.length === 3);   // filter only those of length === 3

console.log(result);
```

Comment: And I am still curious whether there is a way to do it  all by regex...

Comment: I think it'll be hard (if possible) to find a regex that does that in javascript without the use of look-behinds.